# Lync 2010 - Adding an image/banner/web/window to main/chat - (CWE)

Tags: lync-2010, lync

I'm working with Lync 2010 and I'm looking for the way to add a little window (like a CWE) next to the Lync main window or a chat window. Actually I do this but only for a chat, so there are my question:

1) Adding a CWE to the chat: There's any way to implement this without the user needs install a registry setup or insert the keys into the register? I've an own server and for my use (it's an informational banner about company policies) and i want to know if i can modify from server side something that could happen without any user action.

2) How can I this little banner to the main window (the contact list) of the Lync 2010?

The basic idea is use the same CWE or method that load an url but I can accept some work around to do this, ever thinking in the same way: the banner must be change dinamically from outside.

Thanks in advance for answer and suggestions.

The basic idea is something like this: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/29576efc-0d12-4ad8-8ace-6a9a63275a57

With or without the "tabs" aspect/design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1, have a look at "Runtime Registration". This is covered in George Durzi and Michael Greenlee's book, but you should also be able to find info using your favourite search engine.

For your other question, there is no supported way to do what you want using the APIs. Your only option is to use the Lync SDK in UI Suppression mode, but this means you would need to re-write the entire Lync user interface. For an overview of all supported APIs and extensibility points, see [this article](https://blog.chimusoftware.com/post/overview-lync-apis/)

An unsupported option, if you are comfortable with Win32, would be to use Win32 calls to insert your own UI into the Lync client - but this could be messy.

I haven't tried the API at the link you shared yet. It may do the job, but not in a Microsoft supported way, i'm guessing.

Comment: thnks for the tips. I'll keep find and if no one post a better solution i'll acept it :)